# Can't get Spring MVC dispatcher to work properly when url pattern is a path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have a web app that we're applying spring MVC just for REST services at the moment. We want our rest services to appear under `${contextPath}/rest/**`, however when I set this we get:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/rest/testSvc/message] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet'

My `web.xml` has:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml
    </param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`servlet-context.xml`, which is fine and is registering services as they get registered at startup.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myapp.rest" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

My controller looks as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/testService")
public class TestREST {
    @RequestMapping(value="message", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getMessage() {
        return "REST working";
    }
```

If I cahnge the `url-pattern` in `web.xml` to *.rest and my request-mapping for `message` to `message.rest` it works.

Comment: I figured it may be something like that too, however unfortunately that's not the case, the servlet is actually receiving the request which is why it gets logged, however it's not matching correctly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is likely that you have repeated the `/rest` prefix in both `web.xml` and `@RequestMapping`. It should be in one or the either, but not both, e.g.

```
<url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testService")
```

The paths upon which `@RequestMapping` operates are the parts of the path that follows the servlet part, and your `web.xml` defines the servlet part as `/path`, so `@RequestMapping` matches against whatever is left, i.e. `/testService`.

In its current form, your `@RequestMapping` is actually matching against `{contextPath}/rest/rest/testService`.

Comment: Cheers mate, I did try this but couldn't get it to work, problem why is I had `<url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>`, changed it to `/rest/*` and it's working fine now. So the combination of the two were screwing with me. Thanks heaps.

Comment: are there any sources in docummentation about that?

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you could try changing to `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern`> or `<url-pattern>/rest*</url-pattern`> and see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. I can tell that the despatcher is receiving the request as it's logging the error. I guess that if it didn't receive the request it wouldn't log right? /rest* does not get through to the servlet, though /rest/* does.

Comment: Turns out that `/rest/*` is required in combination with skaffman's answer, I up-voted you for this, thanks mate.