# Send AJAX from Javascript to Spring Controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring

I have a JSP page with some javascript on it:

```
function enviar(tableID) {


    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);


    var array= new Array();

    for (var i = 1;i<table.rows.length; i++){

        var row = table.rows[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++){

            alert("added to array: "+row.cells[j].getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0].value);
            array.push(row.cells[j].getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0].value);

        }
    }
    var ajaxRequest;  

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.open('POST', 'proyecto/saveRecompensas');

    ajaxRequest.send('array='+array);

}
```

And a Controller, with a method which should receive the petition AND the array I am sending along with the petition:

```
@RequestMapping ("/proyecto/saveRecompensas")
    public String saveRecompensas(@RequestParam String[] array){
        System.out.println("saveRecompensas method");

        return null;        
    }
```

The problem is, that sysout in the method is never called. This way, when the Javascript is executed, the server console says this:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/proyecto/proyecto/saveRecompensas] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

Why the double "proyecto" in the URI? Which URL should I use to the server can receive the petition? Am I sending well the parameters?

Thank you.

EDIT:

My Dispatcher:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: How did you config springMVC dispetcher in web.xml? Shouldn't it end with a suffix? If no suffix specified, it will be recognized as a folder, not a request path, that's probably why you can't reach it.

Comment: Adding Dispatcher in my question...

Comment: Despite I have no suffix in my Dispatcher, any other petition to the server works in this state, why this dont? Is there any other way to call an URL and send an array without using AJAX?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367309/cant-get-spring-mvc-dispatcher-to-work-properly-when-url-pattern-is-a-path

Comment: I checked it, changed my urlpattern to '/*' and the home page didnt load, changed to '//*' and the home page loaded, but not the rest of the pages. Changed to ´*.*´ and have the same issue as before. The warning says No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/helpin/proyecto/saveRecompensas] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' but in the Controller method I have that exact same URL... Forgive me but Im not exactly a Spring master...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better specify either a suffix or a sub path, not just the root path.

- **sub path approch:**

servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/action/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

action:

```
@RequestMapping ("/proyecto/saveRecompensas")
public String saveRecompensas(@RequestParam String[] array){
    System.out.println("saveRecompensas method");
    return null;        
}
```

url:

```
ajaxRequest.open('POST', 'action/proyecto/saveRecompensas');
```

- **suffix approch:**

servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

action:

```
@RequestMapping ("/proyecto/saveRecompensas")
public String saveRecompensas(@RequestParam String[] array){
    System.out.println("saveRecompensas method");
    return null;        
}
```

url:

```
ajaxRequest.open('POST', 'proyecto/saveRecompensas.action');
```

**@Edit get an array param in controller method:**

- in java:

  - inside @RequestParam, must use 'value="paramName[]"' to specify param names, the name must end with "[]"
  - the parameter should be defined as array type,

  e.g.

  `public Map<String, Object> getObjects(@RequestParam(required = true, value = "ids[]")  Integer[] ids) {
  }`
- in js:

  - the name of array param should also has suffix "[]",

  e.g.
  `"ids[]":[1,2,3]`

Comment: But that means I should have to change all the URL calls in my app, right?

Comment: @Fustigador Honestly, I didn't find a way to make "/*" work, if you found one, please tell me too. You can define a variable for the fixed prefix, then add the variable as prefix, thus in case you need to change the prefix, you only need to change 1 variable. The same for the suffix approch, you add a variable for the suffix, then you can change it if need.

Comment: I have tried this...and its not working. I have now exactly what you suggest, and I receve WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/proyecto/proyecto/saveRecompensas] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet. I try then removing "proyecto" and the slash in the AJAX request...and then I dont receive the warning, but the method is still not called in the Controller.

Comment: Just to clarify. My url pattern is now `<url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>`, my ajaxRequest open method is `ajaxRequest.open('POST', 'saveRecompensas.action');` and in the Controller: `@RequestMapping ("/proyecto/saveRecompensas")` this way, Im not receiving the warn, but the method is never called...

Comment: I eliminated from the signature of the method the `@RequestParam String[] array` and now the method IS called...but I need that array in the Controller

Comment: First, the sub path approach might be better, because spring document use it as example in the MVC chapter. Second, it seems you are not exactly following what I suggestted in the answer. Third, array param is a little special, see the updated answer for detail.

Comment: Its not working... I can do "var array[]" in JS, but the execution stops there. When I am launching the request, I tried to do ajaxRequest.send('array[]='+array), but didn't worked. I know im not exactly doing what you said, but the way I am now I dont receive the warning, and if I left the method signature "saveRecompensas()", withou arguments, The method is called, so I assume the AJAX call its working. Only the pass array from JS to Controler left.

Comment: @Fustigador You didn't understand what I said, I am not asking you to create an array, instead you change the param name, add "[]" to end as part of the param name, you should enclosed it like this "ids[]", inside the double quota.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58378/discussion-between-fly-bird-and-fustigador).

Comment: If you mean doing `ajaxRequest.send('"array[]"='+array);` it does not work. Im not doing "ids[] : [1,2,3]" anywhere in my JS. I cant do `var "array[]"` in JS.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the current URL context is: `/myapp/proyecto` so if you do:

```
ajaxRequest.open('POST', 'proyecto/saveRecompensas');
```

It will base it off the current URL context, adding proyecto again.

Comment: But if I do ´ajaxRequest.open('POST', '/saveRecompensas');´ it does not work, already tried...

Comment: that's because you have a / at the front.  Remove the slash

Comment: another option is to just do ajaxRequest.open('POST', '/myapp/proyecto/saveRecompensas');

Comment: Im going to try those options, will come back in a sec to give feedback.

Comment: Nah, none of the options worked. I tried having it again as in my question, and changing the RequestMapping to "/proyecto/proyecto/saveRecompensas" but it does not work. If I change the open method to what you said, I receive the same warning, but the URL that does not finds is /myapp/proyecto/myapp/proyecto/saveRecompensas

Answer (score 0):

Just add a suffix for your urls' as shown below in web.xml file

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Call controller method from ajax as below code

```
 $.ajax({
        url:"your_url.do",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'somename':data},
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

It will works.